# Add JApplet to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, japplet

I'm attempting to make a drawing application kind of like Microsoft Paint within Bluej, and I'm having a problem with figuring out how to add my `JApplet` to the `JFrame`. I've looked at other questions for help and I don't think others are answering my question exactly. Here is my code from the 3 classes:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
public class StartHere {
    public static void main (String [] args){
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++){
    FirstWindow fw = new FirstWindow();
    fw.setVisible(true);
    paint p = new paint();
    p.setVisible(true);
   }
}
}




import javax.swing.JApplet;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class paint extends JApplet
    implements MouseMotionListener{
   int width, height;
   Image backbuffer;
   Graphics backg;

   JPanel panel = new JPanel();

   public void init() {
      width = getSize().width;
      height = getSize().height;

      backbuffer = createImage( width, height );
      backg = backbuffer.getGraphics();
      backg.setColor( Color.white );
      backg.fillRect( 0, 0, width, height );
      backg.setColor( Color.blue );

      addMouseMotionListener( this ); 
   }

   public void mouseMoved( MouseEvent e ) { }
   public void mouseDragged( MouseEvent e ) {
      int x = e.getX();
      int y = e.getY();
      backg.fillOval(x-5,y-5,10,10);
      repaint();
      e.consume();
    }

   public void update( Graphics g ) {
      g.drawImage( backbuffer, 0, 0, this );
    }

   public void paint( Graphics g ) {
      update( g );
   }
}




import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;

public class FirstWindow extends JFrame{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

String s;
JCheckBox cb, cb2;
JTextField textField;
JLabel label;

public FirstWindow() {
    super ("PAINT");
    
    setSize(1600,800);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    
    
    
    
    JRadioButton b = new JRadioButton ("BLUE");
    JRadioButton r = new JRadioButton ("RED");
    JRadioButton y = new JRadioButton ("YELLOW");
    JRadioButton g = new JRadioButton ("GREEN");
    JRadioButton p = new JRadioButton ("PURPLE");
    JRadioButton o = new JRadioButton ("ORANGE");
    
    
    
    ButtonGroup colors = new ButtonGroup();
    colors.add(b);
    colors.add(r);
    colors.add(y);
    colors.add(g);
    colors.add(p);
    colors.add(o);
    
    add (panel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    
    panel.add(b);
    panel.add(r);
    panel.add(y);
    panel.add(g);
    panel.add(p);
    panel.add(o);
}
}
```

Do I need to place the frame into `StartHere` and import the `JPanel` and applet from the other 2 classes into it?

### Note

I am not close to finishing the app, I still have a lot to update after the applet is connected to the frame, I just need help on this section of the program.

Comment: 1) *"I'm having a problem with figuring out how to add my JApplet to the JFrame."* If you wrote the code for the applet, I'd suggest a different approach entirely. Refactor that code into a `JPanel` that can be added to an applet, a frame, a window, or ..whatever other container it needs to be shown in. 2) *"I've looked at other questions for help and I don't think others are answering my question exactly"* Which questions? Why didn't they help?

Comment: The short answer is don't, generally speaking the applet has a "life cycle" which is typically managed by the browser, the long answer is what Andrew said